# Meaning of 'Isomorphism (with respect to inclusion)'

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, terminology, modules

This is the first time that I see this phrase. I'm reading *Commutative Algebra* by *N.Bourbaki*.

I'll extract 2 propositions that use this phrase. The first one is on page 68 of the book.

> **Proposition 10.**
>
> Let $M$ be an $A-$module. For every submodule $N'$ of the $S^{-1}A-$module $S^{-1}M$, let $\phi(N')$ be the inverse image of $N'$ under the canonical homomorphism $i_M^S: M \to S^{-1}M$. Then:
>
> 1. $S^{-1}\phi(N') = N'$.
> 2. For every submodule $N$ of $M$, the submodule $\phi(S^{-1}N)$ of $M$ consists of those $m \in M$, for which there exists $s \in S$, such that $sm \in M$.
> 3. $\phi$ is an **isomorphism (for the orderings defined by inclusion)** of the set of sub-$S^{-1}A-$modules of $S^{-1}M$ onto the set of submodules $Q$ of $M$, which satisfy the following condition:
>
>    (MS) If $sm \in Q$ for $s \in S$, and $m\in M$, then $m \in Q$.

The second place where I see this is in Proposition 11 on page 70 of the same book (the context here is pretty much the same as the one quoted above). However, the phrase is a little bit different, although, I believe they are the same thing. The phrase used there is: "**isomorphism (with respect to inclusion)**"

When talking about isomorphisms (or generally, homomorphisms), I know that we need some kind of binary operators, intersections, and unions are such operators. However, I'm sure why the author used the word **inclusion** there, I don't think it's an operator.

Thank you very much guys,

And have a good day,

Comment: Relations as well as operations can be preserved, as in the case of order isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is meant is the following. The map $\phi$ is a map from the set of $S^{-1}A$-submodules of $S^{-1}M$ to the set of $A$-submodules of $M$ satisfying the condition (MS). This map, it is claimed, is a bijection and preserves $\subseteq$, i.e., it is an isomorphism of partially ordered sets of certain $S^{-1}A$- (resp. $A$-) modules, ordered by inclusion.

Comment: I think I get it now, does it mean that the following statement holds: $A \subset B \Rightarrow f(A) \subset f(B)$?

Comment: Yes (where $A$ and $B$ are $S^{-1}A$-submodules of $S^{-1}M$ and $f = \phi$).

Comment: Great, thank you so much Magdiragdag. :*

Comment: You're welcome.